# Hibernate Projections for Sub Collections within an Entity

Tags: hibernate

Here is a very simplified example of what I am trying to accomplish with Hibernate and projections.  Here are some sample tables:

```
class User{
    int id;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    List<Address> address ;
}

class Address{
    int id;
    String city;
    String state;   
    User user;
}
```

This how I perform a regular select of the data.

```
Criteria crit = getSession().createCriteria("User");
crit.add(CriterionUtils.in("id", new Object[]{1,2,3}));   
criteria.list();
```

This works and returns the full User object and full Address list.  This will load the complete  User objects with the list of Address objects.

Now I am having trouble understanding how Projections work with Hibernate.  This is my goal.  I have large entities that I have to load but I do not need all the data, I just need a few columns and a sub collection loaded, all the other data I do not need.  Essentially I want to load the same object just with a restricted amount of data.  But, I don't want the firstName and lastName of the User object because I do not need them; I want a "lighter" User object that has the full Address list loaded and the id of the User.  Remember my goal is not to load the Address list but the User object that has the Address list

If i try this:

```
ProjectionList proList = Projections.projectionList();
proList.add(Projections.property("id"));
criteria = criteria.setProjection(proList);      
criteria.list(); //an Object[] of just the ids
```

I only get ids and no User objects!

If I try this:

```
ProjectionList proList = Projections.projectionList();
proList.add(Projections.property("id"));
proList.add(Projections.property("address"));
criteria = criteria.setProjection(proList);      
criteria.list(); //this actually fails with an Array out of bounds exception
```

This just fails!

It seems that Projections only return the exact data you want and not the entity.  I was expecting that the User object to be returned with partially filled fields.

Maybe I am going about this incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

You do it wrong, i guess. Not sure what You really want to attain, but it sounds like you need some lazy / proxy loading in your mapping more, than projections.

Set loading rule to unnecessary columns to `lazy ="true"` for properties or `lazy="proxy"` for collections. Then, they will be not loaded from DB until you try to use them in the code.

Remember also about checking fetch method (`fetch="select"`) and maybe batching - if you have a lot of data in collection, but need only few of them to show at a time.

And if you need that Projection, you should start from Address, because you have some joins in your query. My advice is - try to write the query in SQL first, than put it in Hibernate's Cirteria api (at least until you learn how it works and how to use it properly).